# Python: Absorbing newlines on keyboard input

Tags: python, input

I have a question specific to multi-line input from the keyboard.  It appears that my program is not absorbing newlines.  The effect is that, after the input is processed, the program appears to believe that there are a number of carriage returns pending equal to the number of newline characters in the input.

I have looked at the sys module (sys.stdin.flush()), the msvsrc module (msvcrt.kbhit() and msvcrt.getch()), raw_input, and tried everything I can think of in search, but I'm coming up dry.  Perhaps strip() will work, but I can't seem to figure it out for the general case.

The output I am getting is this:

```
Enter a string: def countLetters():
    s = input("Enter a string: ")
    d = histogram(s.upper())
    printSortedDict(d, True)
('T', 3)
('E', 3)
('F', 1)
('D', 1)
(' ', 1)
(':', 1)
('R', 1)
('(', 1)
('N', 1)
(')', 1)
('L', 1)
('U', 1)
('C', 1)
('O', 1)
('S', 1)

Continue (yes/no): 
Continue (yes/no): 
Continue (yes/no): 
Continue (yes/no):
```

I would like for the output to only have one "Continue (yes/no):" displayed.  It appears that the input() routine is eating the last newline (as expected) but not any of the intermediate newlines.  These newlines appear to be interpreted as input to the "Continue (yes/no):" statement.

I am using Python 3.4.1.  I am developing on Win8 but would like the solution to run on at least Linux as well (in case the solution is platform specific).  Here is the program.  The easiest way to see the problem is just to copy the source code and past it as input to the program.

```
#
# letterCountDict - count letters of input.  uses a dict()
#
"""letterCountDict - enter a string and the count of each character is returned """

# stolen from p. 122 of "Python for Software Design" by Allen B. Downey
def histogram(s):
    """builds a histogram from the characters of string s"""
    d = dict()
    for c in s:
        if c in d:
            d[c] += 1
        else:
            d[c] = 1
    return d

def printSortedDict(d, r=False):
    """sort and print a doctionary.  r == True indicates reserve sort."""
    sl = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=r)
    for i in range(len(sl)):
        print(sl[i])

def countLetters():
    s = input("Enter a string: ")
    d = histogram(s.upper())
    printSortedDict(d, True)

answerList = ["yes", "no"]
done = False
while not done:
    countLetters()
    ans = ""
    while ans not in answerList:
        ans = input("\nContinue (yes/no): ").replace(" ", "").lower()
    if ans == "no":
        done = True
```

Comment: "there are a number of carriage returns pending" — What does that mean?

Comment: what output do you expect?

Comment: What do you mean by "multi-line input"? How are you entering that data?

Answer (score 3):

`input()` doesn't accept multiple lines. Each call to `input()` retrieves exactly one line.

So, you have the first call to input:

```
    s = input("Enter a string: ")
```

receives this line:

```
def countLetters():
```

Sure enough, you can see it has three T's, three E's, and so forth.

The next call to `input()` is this:

```
    ans = input("\nContinue (yes/no): ").replace(" ", "").lower()
```

to which you have typed:

```
s = input("Enter a string: ")
```

Since your response is neither `'yes'` nor `'no'`, your loop asks again. This time you type:

```
d = histogram(s.upper())
```

which is also neither `'yes'` nor `'no'`.

This pattern continues until you get tired of typing nonsense to the question. Finally, you type "no" and the game ends.

If you want to read more than one line at a time, try `sys.stdin.read()` or perhaps `sys.stdin.readlines()`. For example:

```
import sys
def countLetters():
    print("Enter several lines, followed by the EOF signal (^D or ^Z)")
    s = sys.stdin.read()
    d = histogram(s.upper())
    printSortedDict(d, True)
```

Comment: Thank you, Robᵩ!  Not only works perfectly, but actually makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

When you get the input from this line

`s = input("Enter a string: ")` replace it with

`s = input("Enter a string: ").replace('\n', '')`